# "Task never defined" error going from Gulp 3 to Gulp 4

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

I'm trying to convert my gulp 3 file to gulp 4 after upgrading to Node v12, and I'm still erroring out even after reading tutorials/examples. I'm getting the `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task never defined: sass error`

My gulpfile.js file:

```
const gulp        = require('gulp');
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const sass        = require('gulp-sass');

// Compile Sass & Inject Into Browser
gulp.task('sass', gulp.series('sass'), function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'])
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Move JS Files to src/js
gulp.task('js', gulp.series(['js']), function() {
    return gulp.src(['node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', 'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js','node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js'])
        .pipe(gulp.dest("src/js"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// Watch Sass & Serve
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['sass']), function() {

    browserSync.init({
        server: "./src"  
    });

    gulp.watch(['node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss', 'src/scss/*.scss'], gulp.series('sass'));
    gulp.watch("src/*.html").on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

// Move Fonts to src/fonts
gulp.task('fonts', gulp.series(['fonts']), function() {
  return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/fonts'))
})

// Move Font Awesome CSS to src/css
gulp.task('fa', gulp.series(['fa']), function() {
  return gulp.src('node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('src/css'))
})

gulp.task('default', ['js','serve', 'fa', 'fonts']);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start this form is incorrect:

```
gulp.task('sass', gulp.series('sass'), function() {
```

That calls the `'sass'` at the beginning of the `'sass'` task itself.  It would presumably cause an infinite loop.  I suspect it is the cause of your error because you are calling the `'sass'` task before it has been completely defined.

`gulp.task` takes only two arguments: the name and one function, so this is correct:

```
gulp.task('sass', function() {
```

so make that change to **all your tasks** except:

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series(['sass']), function() {
```

where you might want to run the `'sass'` task before starting the server.  But you can still only have two arguments to `gulp.task` so try

```
gulp.task('serve', gulp.series('sass', function() {
```

Finally, this line

```
gulp.task('default', ['js','serve', 'fa', 'fonts']);
```

needs a `gulp.series` to work properly in gulp v4 so try

```
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('js','serve', 'fa', 'fonts'));
```

Once you make all those changes, see if you get any other errors.